# Jackson with JSON: How can I make it ignore additional properties but error on incomplete json?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I know how I can make Jackson to ignore any additional fields in Json, simply by adding 
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class MyDto {
    int someField;
}
```

But side-effect of this is that Jackson now also **accepts incomplete JSON** and fills missing fields with nulls. 
How can I enforce Jackson to require every field to exist in json and still ignore additional fields in it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson explicitly does NOT validate logical POJO contents; instead, you are recommended to use Bean Validation (JSR-303, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_Validation) API implementation; for example one provided by Hibernate project: http://hibernate.org/validator/

This is the approach many frameworks take; for example, DropWizard supports data-binding using Jackson, and then validation (after data-bind, before business logic run) using Bean Validation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if all properties needed are available you need to add the required anotation to the property.

```
@JsonProperty(value = "response", required = true)
public SomeResponse response;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not do actual validation; it only affects things like JSON Schema generation.

Comment: Jackson will not do any validation as by default. But you can either use Bean validation as described by @StaxMan or create you own deserializers and add logic there.